# Calculate radius and angle of circle connecting two vectors

Tags: circles, solid-angle

I have two vectors that lie on a circle. How do I calculate the radius of the circle and the angle between the two lines from the center of the circle to the two vectors?

Comment: Do you mean that you have two points or three points?

Comment: How can two vectors lie on a circle? Do you mean that their endpoints (distinct?) are on the circle?

Comment: The endpoints of two vectors are on the circle.

Comment: Using the chord distance between the two points I calculated the radius of the circle using the equation R = C / ( 2 * sin(A/2)) where C is the chord distance and A is the angle difference between the two vectors. I found the formula at http://www.mathopenref.com/chord.html